# iPhone: Button Level

Tags: iphone

i'm new to iPhone.Is there any way to set 3 images to button, and when I will click the button it will change button image in a circle ? Thanks...

Comment: Do you want the button to change through the different images continuously? E.g. for each click the image changes, and when the last is reached you start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IBAction method for the button click, you can keep a count of which image you are on, and also have all 3 UIImages ready to go (so there isn't the load everytime..unless the images are large (which they shouldn't be for a button) and check it and rotate it basically with something simple like (assumes you have 3 instance variables of UIImages ready that are already initialized with the images.:

```
-(IBAction) myButtonPress:(id)sender {
int imageCounter = 0;

if(imageCounter == 0) {
    [myButtonImage setBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageCounter++;
}
else if(imageCounter == 1) {
    [myButtonImage setBackgroundImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageCounter++;
}
else if(imageCounter == 2) {
    [myButtonImage setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageCounter = 0;
}

//Do other button press stuff
}
```

Comment: I thought about that...I just tried to look for the easiest way...Because in Android they have cool method. Thanks for that Jesse !

Comment: there might be another shorter way, but this is the easiest logically I believe.